# unzip a folder on specific location and delete the zip file

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, child-theme

After the lots of search. I am deciding to post my question here.

Basically i want to upload a zip file in my wordpress site from my admin panel. And also extract this file to specific location with creating a new folder with unique name every time when i am uploading the zip file. After extraction delete the zip file from my server.

I am using some of my custom code for this but no luck and also lot errors.

Hope anyone providing some suggestion to achieve this.